# keepass and angularjs : login form doesn't trigger validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, autologin, keepass

I'm developping an angularjs (v1.2.26) application. And I used KeePass (v2.28), chromeIPass 2.6.8 (google chrome extension) to fill credentials.

I got an issue with the login form: Keepass allow to auto complete (mandatory) username and password fields.

In this case, angularjs dosn't detect the value and consider the form as **invalid** (I can't connect).
[image]

I try a little workaround under but this seems not work each time.
Any idea on how to solve this ?

---

workaround used in ng-controller (doesn't work each time):

```
$scope.focusLogin = function() {
  // try to avoid 'form invalid' state when browser auto-complete form fields
  $('#LoginView_Password').focus();
  $('#LoginView_Password').change();
  $('#LoginView_Password').focus();
  $('#LoginView_Username').focus();
  $('#LoginView_Username').change();
  $('#LoginView_Username').focus();
};
setTimeout($scope.focusLogin, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I switch to [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) mechanism, I do not have this login form anymore.

Anyway, I had found this little workaround using 'trigger' (to put into the login controller). Example that check every second if third party (ex. keepass plugin) fill the form :

```
  $scope.needLogin = true;
  $scope.focusLogin = function() {
    // avoid 'form invalid' state when browser auto-complete form fields
    $('#LoginView_Username').trigger('input');
    $('#LoginView_Password').trigger('input');
    if (!$scope.loginForm.$invalid) {
      // commonService.info('ok, click on login button');
      $scope.needLogin = false;
    }
    if (!$scope.needLogin) {
      return;
    }
    setTimeout($scope.focusLogin, 1000);
  };
```